# Making a call back function for an android app using django-rest-framework-social-oauth2

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am making an android app and to populate the backend with the users data, I am using https://github.com/PhilipGarnero/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2 which saves me a lot of work on doing a lot of stuff myself but now I want to make a callback function that will return certain user data(scores of the users saved in the database of previously logged in users). I tried finding things about it in the documentation but couldn't. It would be great if anyone of you could suggest a way of desgning my callback functions using

https://github.com/PhilipGarnero/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2